# JPA id field is not seralized by Jackson

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, jackson, spring-boot

I am facing a strange issue with Spring + JPA REST services application. When I return JPA entities as JSON objects, the `@Id` annotated field is ignored in the response in every request. It was working few hours ago, I am not sure what changed. I am not able to find any blog post with this similar problem. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve question

Comment: Well I understand your negative vote but I know if someone knows the answer to it, one would not need any more details, I considered that aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was transitive dependency on Spring-data-rest which does not let the `@Id` s to be serialized by Jackson. Once I removed, it works just fine.